# How to convert string value of a cell in excel to numeric to do various calculations?

Tags: java, jxl

```
Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
data = new String[sheet.getColumns()][sheet.getRows()];
data1 = new String[sheet.getColumns()][sheet.getRows()];
for (int j = 0; j <sheet.getColumns(); j++) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) 
    {
        Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
        data[j][i] = cell.getContents();

        System.out.println(data[j][i]);
        // System.out.println(cell.getContents());
    } System.out.println();
}
```

I need to find sum of the array `data[j][i]`, but not able to since its a string.

Answer (score 0):

JXL has a class called `NumberCell` whose `getValue()` method returns a double.

See the documentation [here](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/NumberCell.html).

So if you change your data array to be double you could replace:

```
Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
data[j][i] = cell.getContents();
```

with:

```
NumberCell cell = (NumberCell)sheet.getCell(j, i);
data[j][i] = cell.getValue();
```

And then you could do calculations on it.

Of course, if you know the value to be an integer, you can cast it accordingly.

Note that it'll be best to check the type first, e.g.:

```
if (sheet.getCell(j, i).getType() == CellType.NUMBER)
```

And wrap it with try/catch whenever converting unknown / unchecked input.